# Missing operations with Axis generated Stub

Tags: axis, wsdl2java

I have an wsdl and I want to create a java stub-client by using Axis2 (WSDL2Java).

Because the generation is made at runtime and because of the structure of the system itself, I call the wsdl2java by using reflection:

```
    Class<?> clzzOptionParser = classloader.loadClass("org.apache.axis2.util.CommandLineOptionParser");
            Class<?> clzzEngine = classloader.loadClass("org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine");
            String[] args = new String[]{"-uri", wsdl.getAbsolutePath(),
                "-o", myJavaCompilerComponent.getOutputPath().getAbsolutePath(),
                "-p", packageName,
                "-ap"
                };

            Object optionParser = clzzOptionParser.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class<?>[]{String[].class}).newInstance(new Object[]{args});
            Object engine = clzzEngine.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class<?>[]{clzzOptionParser}).newInstance(optionParser);

            clzzEngine.getMethod("generate").invoke(engine);
```

I use "-ap" - Parameter to tell the generator to include all porttypes. And though the generated stub contains inner classes (incl. Request und response classes) for all types, only the method (to call the service) of the first type is generated.

How can I enable AXIS to create everything? I thought -ap would do the trick, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by splitting up the WSDL file into multiple files including one operation each.